# Hive/Beeline, how can I set the job .staging directory?

Tags: hadoop, hive, beeline

On the cluster I'm working on every user is given 60GB of Hadoop quota.
Historically the project I'm working on generates a lot of Hive queries.
In order for things to work faster I'm trying to parallel these queries (which are unrelated) but as a result the directory /user/{myusername}/.staging/ is being filled with job_{someid} directories which in turn are filled with the hive jars and consume these 60GB very fast. While I can limit the parallelization factor I would also like to see if I can ask Hive to put these jars on a different directory. Say /tmp/{myusername} where I have a lot more space.

Any idea how do I tell Hive/Beeline to create the .staging directory under /tmp/{myusername}?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is on execution of your beeline session.

```
beeline --hive.exec.stagingdir=/tmp/{myusername}
```

Think you can do it via !set inside beeline but don't have the syntax to hand.

Answer (score 0):

The above doesn't work.

We found the following working

beeline --hiveconf hive.exec.stagingdir=/tmp/{myusername}