# Hive Could not set permission for staging directory

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

My hive job fails with below error even I set exec directory and scratch directory before run job and I am not sure why default properties are not getting updated.

```
SET hive.exec.scratchdir=/domain/usecase/warehouse/hive_scratch_tmp;
SET hive.exec.stagingdir=/domain/usecase/warehouse/.staging;
```

Exception:

> 17/09/13 11:30:42 [Thread-126]: ERROR mr.ExecDriver: yarn
>   java.io.IOException: Could not set permission for
>   /var/mapr/cluster/yarn/rm/staging/usecase/.staging/job_1503499283269_761069/job.jar
>           at com.mapr.fs.MapRFileSystem.setPermission(MapRFileSystem.java:2100)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobResourceUploader.copyJar(JobResourceUploader.java:248)

are there any other property that I need to set? Thanks

There is a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37908837/hive-beeline-how-can-i-set-the-job-staging-directory), property I am already using.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below configuration property in the hive shell to override hive-mapreduce AM stage directory. Use the full URI

`yarn.app.mapreduce.am.staging-dir`

http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Default+mapred+Parameters